# Why am I getting a Fatal error with this MongoDB function?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, csv

I've got a simple php script for getting a csv file into array and inserting each row into MongoDB (CD Collection). But somehow insert returns an error after first successful one:

```
"Fatal error: in C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo\lesson1\index.php on line 17"
```

Here's the code. What could possibly cause such an error? DB receives only one (first).

```
$filename = 'd:/cd_col.csv'; // Each line: Title;No. of CD with movie
$csvfile = fopen($filename,'rb'); 
while(!feof($csvfile)) {
    $csvarray[] = fgetcsv($csvfile);
}
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->mymovies;
$collection = $db->movies;
$id=0;
foreach($csvarray as $key=>$value)
{
    $movie = explode(';', $value[0]);
    $fmovie = array('_id'=>++$id, 'title'=>$movie[0], 'cdno'=>$movie[1]);
    if($collection->save($fmovie)===true) { // this is line 17
        echo 'Successful insert: '.$key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Line 17: if($collection...

Comment: If I leave only: $collection->save($fmovie); it still produces error

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Cannot use save in php, that's it.
You should use $collection->insert(); instead.